# 'I've never been on' vs. 'I've already been on'

Tags: present-perfect

> I've never been on a ship before. It's a fantastic experience.
>
> I've already been on a ship before. It's a fantastic experience.

Are both options correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: All four sentences are grammatically correct, but they don't necessarily make sense. Could you edit your question to specify what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

They're both grammatical, though the second is awkward, and a bit paradoxical. They have completely different meanings.

"I've never been on a ship before" = "This is the first time I've ever been on a ship".

"I've already been on a ship before" = "This is **not** the first time I've been on a ship". "Already" implies "before", so it is redundant to say "before", and I don't know why anybody would. I say paradoxical, because remarking that it is a fantastic experience is a bit unlikely when this isn't the first time; but not an impossible thing to say.

Comment: "I've never been on a ship before" can also mean the speaker has never been on a ship; not now, not ever. For example: `Colin:` _J.R., have you ever been on a ship before?_ `J.R.:` _No, Colin, I haven't, but I've heard it's a fantastic experience. My grandmother used to tell me about a cruise she took when she was younger._

Comment: To me, the "before" is anomalous if you're not on a ship now. But YMMV.